# Component in ternary operator is rendered unusually

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Below is my code,

`

```
return(
   <section>
      <div className={isSidebarEnable}>
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.       <Row className="mb-2">
                <Col md={12}>
                  <div className={`${styles.card} card`}>
                    <NetworkChart NetworkChartData={NetworkChartData} />
                  </div>
                </Col>
      </div>
      {isLoading ? <Loader /> : <></>}
    </section>
  );
};
```

`

can someone explain me the line {isLoading ? :<></>} in the above code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: small correction
{isLoading ? <Loader/>:<></>}

Comment: If `isLoading` evaluates to true it will render `<Load />` otherwise it will render nothing `<></>`..

Comment: You have a state variable called `isLoading`. When its true, you will show `<Loader/>` component. When its false, you will render `<></>` which is a React.Fragment component. So its as good as no component as it will filtered out in virtual dom. Better implementation would be to return `null` in case of false. React.Fragment is suitable for case when you want a component to return more than 1 Node

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable named isLoading that would probably be a boolean value,

```
{isLoading ? <Loader /> : <></>}
```

From this code, if the isLoading variable is true it will show the `<Loader />`
component otherwise it will show nothing.